# Issue with certificate import

Tags: command-line, import, certificate

In our code we are trying to import certificates from source code to user's system who tries to install our application.Our application is windows application.

To import certificate they have used key tool command where path is wrong.

```
<Command name="User">
   <![CDATA[keytool -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs" 
           -import -v -noprompt 
           -file "C:\Program Files\American Express\DesktopPhone\AppletWeb\cert\NIVRApplet.cert" 
           -alias nap  -storepass ""]]>
</Command>
```

Even though path `C:\Program Files\American Express\DesktopPhone\AppletWeb\cert\NIVRApplet.cert` is not available still certificate is getting imported into user system in the location `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs` when they install our application.

When I try executing the above command in command prompt directly it says import is unsuccessful but it works fine through application without any error with certificate getting imported.

I am not sure how it is happening?

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

> When I try executing the above command in command prompt directly it
>   says import is unsuccessful but it works fine through application
>   without any error with certificate getting imported.

Probably the account you logged in does not have necessary permission on the keystore you are trying to import. What error you are getting ?